# Annotations not appearing

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mapkit, plist

I can't seem to get my annotations to pop up on my map view. I have a ton of annotations from a plist and they're not showing up on the map except for one. help please?

map viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface Map_ViewController : UIViewController
<CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate >

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

map ViewController.m

```
#import "Map ViewController.h"
#import "MADAnnotation.h"
@interface Map_ViewController ()

@end

#define CHARMANDER_LATITUDE 40.0078429;
#define CHARMANDER_LONGITUDE -105.26966709999999;

#define CHARMELEON_LATITUDE 40.0104104;
#define CHARMELEON_LONGITUDE -105.28965619999997;

#define CHARIZARD_LATITUDE 40.0064377;
#define CHARIZARD_LONGITUDE -105.27301119999998;

#define BULBASAUR_LATITUDE 40.0096216;
#define BULBASAUR_LONGITUDE -105.27282120000001;

#define IVYSAUR_LATITUDE 40.0108876;
#define IVYSAUR_LONGITUDE -105.27389820000002;

#define VENUSAUR_LATITUDE 40.0079411;
#define VENUSAUR_LONGITUDE -105.27507350000002;

#define SQUIRTLE_LATITUDE 40.0043601;
#define SQUIRTLE_LONGITUDE -105.26956860000001;

#define WARTORTLE_LATITUDE 40.0104104;
#define WARTORTLE_LONGITUDE -105.26633140000001;

#define BLASTOISE_LATITUDE 40.0104961;
#define BLASTOISE_LONGITUDE -105.26594160000002;


#define THE_SPAN 0.20f;

@implementation Map_ViewController
{
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
MADAnnotation *annotation;


}

@synthesize mapView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {



    mapView.delegate=self;
    mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeHybrid;
    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; locationManager.delegate=self;  locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest; locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;


    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];




    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    //Center
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = BULBASAUR_LATITUDE;
    center.longitude = BULBASAUR_LONGITUDE;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = center;
    myRegion.span=span;

    //Set our mapView
    [mapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];



    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PokeLocations" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"PokeLocations"];
    NSLog(@"read1");

    for(int i = 0; i < [anns count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"read2");
        float realLatitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
        float realLongitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];
        NSLog(@"read3");

        MADAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MADAnnotation alloc] init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
        theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;
        myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
        myAnnotation.title = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        myAnnotation.subtitle = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Subtitle"];
        [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];
        //[myAnnotation release];
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{


    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=.001;
    span.longitudeDelta=.001;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center= manager.location.coordinate;
    region.span=span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    if(annotation){
        [annotation moveAnnotation:manager.location.coordinate];
    }
    else {
        annotation=[[MADAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:manager.location.coordinate];
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];     }
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSString *errorType;
    if (error.code == kCLErrorDenied) {
        errorType=@"Access Denied";
    } else errorType=@"Error";
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"

                                                  message:errorType delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation1
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation1 reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
    }

    //Custom Pin
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pokeballsmall2.png"];

    //Custom Thumbnail (left side)
    UIImageView *IconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pokeballsmall.png"]];
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = IconView;

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.annotation = annotation1;

    return annotationView;


}


@end
```

MADAnnotation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MADAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImageView * leftCalloutAccessoryView;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coor;
-(void) moveAnnotation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate;

@end
```

MADAnnotation.m

```
 #import "MADAnnotation.h"

@implementation MADAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle, leftCalloutAccessoryView;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coor{ coordinate=coor;
    title=@"You are here";
    subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude: %f. Longitude: %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude]; return self;
}


-(void) moveAnnotation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];         [self willChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];     coordinate = newCoordinate;
    subtitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Latitude: %f. Longitude: %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
}


@end
```

annotations.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PokeLocations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#004 Charmander</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Fire Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0078429</string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.26966709999999 </string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#005 Charmeleon</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Fire Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0104104</string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.28965619999997</string>
        </dict>
         <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#006 Charizard</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Fire/Flying Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0064377  </string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.27301119999998 </string>
        </dict>
         <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#001 Bulbasaur</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Grass/Poison Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0096216</string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.27282120000001 </string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#002 Ivysaur</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Grass/Poison Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0108876</string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.27389820000002 </string>
        </dict>
         <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#003 Venusaur</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Grass/Poison Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0079411</string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.27507350000002 </string>
        </dict>
         <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#007 Squirtle</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Water Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0043601</string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.26956860000001 </string>
        </dict>
         <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#008 Wartortle</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Water Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0104961</string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.26633140000001</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>#009 Blastoise</string>
            <key>Subtitle</key>
            <string>Water Type</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <string>40.0104961</string>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <string>-105.26594160000002 </string>
        </dict>
    </array>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: the one that is appearing - is it the last annotation from the plist?

Comment: no nothing is showing up from the plist. It's coming from the location manager in the map view controller

Comment: Is this the actual code that's running?  This line in viewDidLoad should not work: `myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;` because in the `MADAnnotation` class, the `coordinate` property is marked as readonly.  Why are you doing `init` instead of `initWithCoordinate`?  Is the code actually entering that `for` loop?

Comment: This is actually what I was just about to post about. I can't figure out how to fix that line in viewDidLoad

Comment: I just changed it to assign. It's working now! Is there anyway to make a clickable button on the callouts to redirect to a different part of the app

Answer (score 0):

I could not reply on comments so I posted it as an answer

you can use the following method to add properties to your annotations :

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapMKMapView viewForAnnotation:       (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation       reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple; // <--for coloring purpose 

UIButton *adverButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[adverButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = adverButton;
MyPin.draggable = YES;
MyPin.highlighted = YES;
MyPin.animatesDrop  = TRUE;
MyPin.canShowCallout  = YES;

return MyPin;
}

-(void)button:(id)sender
{
  //add your nextView you want to open here
}
```